# how to write lightning:select in aura:iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am creating list of `lightning:select` in an `aura:iteration` and in each `lightining:select` consists of list of items and I want to get each index of the `lightning:select` of each iteration to find which `lightning:select` is changed the value. I have tried some code

I am trying to put the data-value to get the index in javascript but lightning is not allowing me to put data-value on `lightning:select`

```
<aura:iteration items="{!tableList}" var="set" indexVar="childindex">

<td>
    <ui:outputtext class="slds-align_absolute-center" value="{!childindex + 1}"> </ui:outputtext>
</td>

<td>

    <a style="color:black" data-id="{!masterindex}">

        <lightning:select class="label-hidden" value="{!set.field}" data-value="{!childindex}" onchange="{!c.onHeaderChange}">
            <option text="Select any value" value="" />
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.headerOptions}" var="Option">
                <option text="{!Option.label}" value="{!Option.value}" />
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:select>

    </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written some sample code which will help you in understanding how to identify which lightning: select value is changed for which field.

I have basically added a div, assigned the index value as id and making use of event.target to get the index when picklist is changed.

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="tableList" type="List" default="['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3']"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.tableList}" var="set" indexVar="childindex">   
        <td>
            <ui:outputtext class="slds-align_absolute-center" value="{!childindex + 1}"> </ui:outputtext>
        </td>

        <td>  
            <div id="{!set}">
                <lightning:select aura:id="picklist" name="select" label="" onchange="{! c.onHeaderChange }">
                    <option value="">choose one...</option>
                    <option value="apple">apple</option>
                    <option value="pumpkin">pumpkin</option>
                    <option value="cherry">cherry</option>
                    <option value="blueberry">blueberry</option>
                    <option value="pickle">pickle</option>
                </lightning:select>
            </div>
        </td>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

controller:

```
({
    onHeaderChange : function(component, event, helper) {
        var selectedField = event.target.id;
        var selectedValue = event.getSource().get("v.value");
        console.log(selectedValue + ' is selected for field :: ' + selectedField);
    }
})
```

let me know if it helps..

[image]